# Which property of transversality enables Whitney's (weak) embedding? (Guillemin/Pollack)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

In Guillemin & Pollack *Differential Topology* it says on P.49 with regards to Whitney's weak embedding theorem (i.e. every smooth $k$-manifold can be embedded in $2k + 1$ euclidean space):

> Why $N = 2k + 1$? As we see it, the underlying geometrical reason why $2k + 1$ space can accomodate all $k$-dimensional manifolds is a basic property of transversality that will be proved in the next chapter.

Unfortunately, they never really talk about the topic again. At least not explicitly. From what I've read I suspect that some dimension counting argument is involved, but I really don't know which of the theorems in their chapter on transversality ensures Whitney's weak theorem the needed wiggle room in $\mathbb{R}^{2k +1}$. I would really appreciate it if someone could maybe explain their thoughts a bit more.

Comment: Basically embed your $k$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and if $N>2k+1$ (repeatedly) find a direction (which is not a tangent or secant) to project.

Comment: @user10354138: Yes, i know this part of the proof of Whitneys weak Theorem. But I don't really see the direct connection to transversality. The proof that there exists an injective immersion when $N > 2k +1$ usually uses Sard's theorem. Asked the other way around: Can we give an easy argument for why this fails, when $N \leq 2k + 1$?

Comment: The proof uses not even the full Sard's theorem, but the following Lemma:  If $f : M \to N$ be a smooth functions so that $\dim M < \dim N$, then $f$ is not surjective. And in some sense, there is no argument as to why **this** fails when $N\le 2k+1$: the Whitney embedding theorem holds for $N = 2k$, just that the proof from $2k+1$ to $2k$ is far more difficult and is not covered in the book.

Comment: They explain it right after that remark! Wiggling something $k$-dimensional (by, say, the Transversality Homotopy Theorem) to make it transverse to something (else) also $k$-dimensional in dimension $\ge 2k+1$  requires transversality by default, i.e., not intersecting at all.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Unfortunately, I don't really understand the relationship of transversality to embeddings in this remark. In the context of Whitney's Embedding Theorem I'm thinking about a _single_ $k$-manifold that I want to embed in some euclidean space. Why are they now talking about two submanifolds? And why would I want them to be transverse to get an embedding? I don't understand how these concepts relate to embeddings.

Comment: Guillemin explained his heuristic remark, as I said, in the sentences following the remark. If you choose to ignore what he said, then move on. It is intuition, not rigorous mathematics. If you want more context, read about handle bodies.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Following your previous comment I, of course, re-read the section. It is just that I don't understand what the authors want to tell me, not that i choose to ignore it...